# Jenkins login: Cannot login via LDAP plugin after switch to JRE 64-bit

Tags: apache, jenkins, ldap, jenkins-plugins

We've beeing using Jenkins running on Windows Server 2008 and JRE 32-bit.
For user authentication we use the LDAP plugin in Jenkins. Jenkins runs behind Apache web server running on the same machine.

Now, to have more memory for the build jobs, we want to switch from JRE 32-bit to JRE 64-bit when starting Jenkins. After this switch Jenkins itself starts properly, the login mask appears but the problem is that we cannot login (user name/pwd are correct)!

Do you know the reason of the problem and how it can be solved? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue before on AIX. Jenkins pointed to some other location after java migration. Re-Setting the catalina_opts and jenkins_home paths resolved my issue.

`$ export CATALINA_OPTS="-DJENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins_home/"`

`$ export JENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins_home/`

add the following to apache context descriptor to avoid this in future

`<Context ...>
  <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/path/to/jenkins_home/" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>`

make sure you have correct java_home set in the environment and then restart Apache

Note: For windows server, define/add environment variables for Jenkins_home and catalina_opts